# Counting total number of subjects in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I count the total number of participants, if the same identifying "subject number" crops up in a column?
I.e for this case below I have 5 participants in total.

For eg.

```
99976
99976
106281
106281
106281
106281
120509
120509
122836
122836
124310
124310
124310
124310
```

And I have at least >1000 in total.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a page about this, I think this might be of help. It uses SUM, IF, FREQUENCY and MATCH functions.

[Count occurrences of values or unique values in a data range](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx#BMcount_the_number_of_unique_values_by_)

Answer (score 0):

You want this code, assuming your list is all in Column A

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A11,A1:A11)>0,1))
```

You will need to update it to match the number of rows you are using (I used 11 in the example above)

[image]

In your case, you may need to do something like like

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A1000,A1:A1000)>0,1))
```

And to show what I changed: =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A **1000**,A1:A **1000**)>0,1))